# postgres aggregate results from joined table

Tags: postgresql

Newbie Postgres question.

I have the following tables

**players**: id, name, ...

**votes**: id, player_id, week - i.e. in votes there will be multiple records for each player_id

I want to get `name (from players), vs: week[] (from votes where player_id == players.id)`

i.e. I want to know which weeks each player voted in

```
select players.name, votes.week
  from public.votes
  join public.players
  ON votes.player_id = players.id
```

gets me the number of results in the votes in table, but that includes endless duplicates of `name`. I want 1 row per player, with the weeks in a list

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by the players' name and use `array_agg` to get an array of weeks:

```sql
SELECT   players.name, ARRAY_AGG(votes.week)
FROM     public.votes
JOIN     public.players ON votes.player_id = players.id
GROUP BY playes.name
```

Comment: You deserve all your points :-)